# REACT JavaScript how to use a custom Class Name?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, web

I am trying to create a custom Class Name for use in a REACT Component.  I am using the map function to create multiple control elements.  I want to be able to specify which UnitSelector this is so my error validation will highlight the correct control.

Here is the render code:

```
    units ?
    units.map((unit, index) => {

        return (
            <div> 
                <UnitSelector className={ this.state.errors.unit + index }
```

Here is the validation code:

```
    let errors = {};
    let errorFound = false;
    let tempUnits = this.state.units;

    //Can only add a new unit, if every Unit Selector has selected a unit.
    for( let i = 0; i < tempUnits.length; i++ ) {
        if( !tempUnits[i] || !tempUnits[i].number ) {
            errorFound = true;
            let fieldName = "unit" + i;
            errors[fieldName] = 'custom-error';
        }
    }

    if( !errorFound ) tempUnits.push();

    this.setState({ units: tempUnits, errors: errors });
```

I believe everything is working correctly except for this part.

```
            <UnitSelector className={ this.state.errors.unit + index }
```

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I ended up going with was to apply a field className to the Unit, so that when it is mapped the className is applied to the UnitSelector.

```
    let tempUnits = [];
    tempUnits.push({ className: "" });

    this.state = {
        errors: {},
        units: tempUnits
    };
```

The render now looks like this:

```
    <UnitSelector  className={ unit.className }
```

The validation code has been changed to this:

```
    addUnit() {

    let errors = {};
    let errorFound = false;
    let tempUnits = this.state.units;

    //Can only add a new unit, if every Unit Selector has selected a unit.
    for( let i = 0; i < tempUnits.length; i++ ) {
        if( !tempUnits[i] || !tempUnits[i].number ) {
            errorFound = true;
            tempUnits[i].className = 'custom-error';
        }
        else {
            //Clear this out to remove the custom error.
            tempUnits[i].className = "";
        }
    }

    if( !errorFound ) tempUnits.push({className: ""});

    this.setState({ units: tempUnits, errors: errors });

}
```